# Latex error: File 'typearea.sty' not found

Tags: errors

When I try to run my LaTeX file in TeXnicCenter, it's giving following error:

```
Latex error: File 'typearea.sty' not found
```

What would be the reason?

Comment: does an update help? [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: Which TeX distro ? typearea.sty is part of koma-script bundle install http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39850/ ,verify it using `kpsewhich typearea.sty` if you are on TeXLive

Comment: @texenthusiast: The KPathSea library is also available on MiKTeX. Hence `kpsewhich` would work there, too.