# New installation – TeX editor says: "Error: Could not start the command"

Tags: errors, compiling, installing, texmaker, editors

I just downloaded and installed Texmaker. I've never used any (La)TeX before.

When I click the Run button with an arrow next to "Quick build" I get an error saying "Could not start the command". Why? What do I need to do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Did you also install MiKTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: Nope, didn't know I had to. TexMaker documentation says nothing of the sort :S But I'll try, thanks.
Are there any differences between them that concerns a beginner?

Comment: After isntalling MikTex, what should I do? :S

Comment: I am not an expert on the differences, but I'd recommend `TexLive` with which you have _all_ the packages downloaded and ready to go. I had an issue with `MikTeX` as I had installed it as `admin` (well I think that was the issue -- really did not spend time looking into it), and then switched to `TeXLive` (both on Mac and PC).

Comment: @David: You're fast, I was just writing up an answer `:D`. Restart Texmaker, and if it still doesn't find the MiKTeX binaries by itself, I'd just reinstall Texmaker. I hope you installed MiKTeX as the single-user install, cf. my upcoming answer.

Comment: @PeterGrill If you choose the MiKTeX Net-Installer, you also get all packages; however, the on-the-fly installation is pretty neat as well. Installing MiKTeX as admin is indeed rarely helpful, see the link in my answer.

Comment: I didn't really try to figure out the problem, but didn't think it worthwhile to download packages on the fly, disk space is rather inexpensive to have to worry about a one time hit of few GB. But, good answer.

Comment: Thanks DonCherry. Seems to be working even though I'm "missin" a .cls file now. Someone should write a quicker quick guide! :) ... ...

"in just one application." in the summary on TexMaker's website made me oblivious to the fact that I might need a compiler.

Comment: @David There is a good installation/ documentation/tutorials in the french version of texmaker click the "disponible ici" at the top of the this page. webpage.http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc_fr.html

Comment: texlearner: Well... It's in French... Got it up and running now.

Comment: (@David: When responding to someone's comment, don't forget the `@username` so they'll be notified.) So everything's up and running now?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Commands paths in TeXstudio on Mac OS X - with 'could not start the command' error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38627)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(Also check out the [MiKTeX tag wiki](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/miktex/info) I just wrote up!)

The hardest part about getting started with LaTeX probably is learning what the different components you need are. Texmaker is an *editor*, but what actually compiles your source code and creates the document is within a (La)TeX *distribution*, the most popular of which are MiKTeX (Windows only) and TeX Live (Windows, Linux, OS X (as *MacTeX*)). You can read about some differences between the two at [What are the advantages of TeX Live over MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/what-are-the-advantages-of-tex-live-over-miktex). I've always been using MiKTeX, which seems like a solid choice for a beginner to me. I am, however, considering trying out TeX Live as well.

If you decide in favor of MiKTeX, make sure to install the *user mode* (you're asked about that during the installation process), not in *admin mode*. It has nothing to do with multi-account configurations, but rather something network-y related. You can read about it at [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67712/4012). But believe me, the user mode will make your life much easier. I wish I would've done it right away. (On another question that might come up before downloading MiKTeX: [What is the difference between the basic MiKTeX and the complete MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1713/4012))

Once you installed a distribution, you might have to reinstall Texmaker if you want to avoid having to (find out and) type in all the paths yourself.

As introductory reading for LaTeX, I recommend [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), which also has a section about the different parts of a working LaTeX system, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! I was about to install Miktex in admin mode, as I do that will all my apps.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I closed `miktex-console` then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue(on Manjaro/Arch Linux). Delete / rename (safer) the .texlive directory in the home directory, and reinstall texlive-core. That would solve it.

Comment: Manjaro is ***not*** Arch.

Comment: @cfr, No it isn't. But it uses the same repos. So the behaviour can be expected to be similar.

Comment: But it often is not similar as the record shows. Especially when things don't work properly ;). It is perfectly safe to delete `~/.texliveYYYY` since it contains only generated files. (Unless somebody has deliberately put other things there for some reason.) I doubt you need to also reinstall `texlive-core` which won't (ought not) touch your home directory. It is probably a stale file or something if removing that directory solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem with you but i solve it finally:) I should explain my situation first, i use windows 7. The reason for me to have the error is i just download MikTeX(really takes a long time) and NOT install MikTex from the package i download before.

Basically for Windows, 2 steps:

Step 1: **install** and **download** MikTex which is a distribution for windows (Note: remember to install after downloading all the package)

Step 2: download Texmaker which is text editor

Here are some useful guides for you if you use windows
http://www.howtotex.com/howto/installing-latex-on-windows/
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RL15I-6NQFQ

Hope that helps you and enjoy you day:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message with the bibliography backend `biber`.

`Error: Could not start the command: biber`

And I had not installed the package biber. (!)
After installing, everything went smooth.

So, first of all, take a look if the package or command is installed, that is, if it can be executed in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, I've been following the solutions proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98129/texstudio-compile-error-could-not-start-the-command-pdflatex-exe). However, when I change the path for pdfLaTeX in the command section in preferences, I can compile but **not compile & view**. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In my case (not for fresh install, but the relevant question is closed as a duplicate of this), the issue was that I added an argument to the `pdflatex` command line that tripped TexStudio up. In particular, I added `-aux-directory=tex-build`. While this works fine if run directly from the shell, for some reason it doesn't work from TexStudio, it seems the dash confuses it: I replaced that with `-aux-directory=texbuild` (notice that the value doesn't have a dash now) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue.

Symptom: `which pdflatex` or `where pdflatex` failed, meaning `pdflatex` was not found in any directory on `PATH`.

The problem seems to have been an overly long `PATH` environment variable. There's a systemwide one and a per-user one that gets appended to form the effective value.

I edited the environment variable; I reordered a few of the paths in there, moving the MikTeX path up.