# Problems with texstudio (New computer)

Tags: compiling, viewers, build-system

I just got a new computer today, its an inspiron 3542, which runs on windows 8.1 and a 64-bit OS. After which i download texstudio to edit some documents, everything works fine until i try to build and compile. When i press compile / build & view nothing updates at all, the document remains the same. But i do notice that on the bottom right there is a message that reads:

Failed to find "C:\Users\ -----\AppData\Local\Temp\texstudio_Zy5708.pdf"; perhaps it has been deleted

I had the same problem on another computer after i downloaded it, which also had a 64 bit OS and ran on windows 8.1

I am pretty new to this latex thing, therefore im not exactly the greatest at understanding it in complex terms. So please try to answer in a way that is understandable if at all possible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Does [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84357/new-installation-texmaker-quick-build-says-could-not-start-the-command?rq=1) help? TeXStudio is just an editor. It can't compile anything. You need also to install a TeX distribution. MiKTeX and TeX Live are the two most popular choices.

Comment: Oh well i feel pretty dumb haha thank you, So when i download this is should work like a charm?

Comment: Can I vote to close this as a duplicate? (It is a very common misunderstanding. At least 2 questions like this yesterday.) And, yes, it should work. If it doesn't, ask a new question explaining which distribution you've installed.

Comment: yes of course, if this is harmful to the community then it shouldn't even be asked :) or maybe i should just delete it?

Comment: Not harmful at all. But it saves repeating answers people have already written, while pointing anybody who finds your question when searching to useful information. That is, it just keeps things tidy. (I think it also improves the site statistics but I don't actually have any idea why that matters. Just people talk about it a bit so I suppose it does.)

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to make like a "sticky" question so then if people have this same trivial yet common question it can be answered right away.

Comment: On a forum, that would be the best solution. Unfortunately, I don't think Stack Exchange makes that possible. You can order questions by frequency or by votes or whatever but there's no equivalent of forum stickies. I guess it is just different software.