# How to build .tex by texmaker?

Tags: texmaker

I am using windows 8 and texmaker 4.4.1
I downloaded a template from [LaTeX_Templates_Resume](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wilson-resume-cv)

Then I open the cv_13.tex and use QuickBuild, then I received the following comments:
Error : could not start the command : pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode


I am afraid that libraries may be missing or a building link should be used but I have no idea how to fix it, anyone knows the problem?

Comment: texmaker is just an editor, have you installed a tex system such as texlive or miktex?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84357/new-installation-texmaker-quick-build-says-could-not-start-the-command?rq=1

Comment: Try to configure texmaker. Go to Options->configure texmaker and  try to open the pdflatex.exe