# How do I avoid pdflatex error in TexMaker?

Tags: errors, pdftex, tex-core, texmaker

I'm new to TeX. I've downloaded TexMaker and trying to run "Quick Build" after simple code written. But I get that pdflatex-related error.

Since my settings in "Options" -> "Configure Texmaker" -> "Command" -> "LaTeX" are standard: "latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
And in in "Options" -> "Configure Texmaker" -> "Command" -> "PdfLaTeX" are standard too: "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
I cannot find solve on the Internet too, because most cases were solved by making those parameters standard (and I already have them standard).

Please help.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Do you have a tex distribution installed? TeXLive or MikTeX come to mind, as it seems you are on windows?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm on Win7. I have MikTeX installed, however I didn't linked it to TexMaker manually. I suppose it was done in installation process, or not, since it's not working.

Comment: Maybe try if it works with the full path to `latex`.

Comment: If you installed TexMaker before MikTex, then just uninstall Texmaker and reinstall it.   This will set the links automatically. (Note on WIN7 you need to do a system restart between the uninstall and the install. )(

Comment: Read this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84357/new-installation-texmaker-quick-build-says-could-not-start-the-command?rq=1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by resinstalling the programs; reported by op in "answer" that would have been a comment if reputation allowed.